# nsurlsession post label.text value to php server execute and return a JSON value

Tags: php, ios, nsurlsession, nsurlsessiondownloadtask, nsurlsessionuploadtask

I need to properly handle a label in my applicaiton flow.  How can I do this?  The steps are

- INPUT: plain text label
- convert to lower-case
- remove spaces
- send to PHP server
- assign to a $value in SQL
- submit request to the server's data base
- OUTPUT: return results (in JSON) to my app

The present design has 11 groups that I send to a different web address according to the page clicked; I would like to scale up to 102 groups.

I thought it would be possible using a nsurlsession to post my label.text (groups name), send that to my server, insert it into my SQL code, and  receive the search result.

```
// Toggle View Button (on button click open next view controller and populate table view with group matching data)
```

- (IBAction)ShowModels:(id)sender {

```
// 1. URL of the server page i want to send data to.
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.website.com/group.php"];

// 2. some how adapt this code to send grouplabel.text in plain text in lowercase without spaces.
NSDictionary *params = @{@"tableName": _groupLabel.text};

// 3. Adapt code to post the value of grouplabel.text to server.
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

// 4. use a task to upload the data to the server and then have another task to recieve the completed data.
NSURLSessionDataTask *task = [[NSURLSession sharedSession] dataTaskWithRequest:request
                                                             completionHandler:^(NSData *data,
                                                                                 NSURLResponse *response,
                                                                                 NSError *error)
                              {
                                  if (!error)
                                  {
                                      NSLog(@"Status code: %li", (long)((NSHTTPURLResponse *)response).statusCode);
                                  }
                                  else
                                  {
                                      NSLog(@"Error: %@", error.localizedDescription);
                                  }
                              }];

// 5. Run the completed task.
[task resume];
```

}

What do I need to change in these stages?

Server side code:

```
<?php 

//connect to database.
include '../Includes/db-connect.php';

//set the table name variable

$table = "name"; //attach label.text value to this...

//Select all distinct values from table name.
$sql = "SELECT DISTINCT make FROM $table";

$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql) or die ("Error in selecting" . mysqli_error($conn));

//create an array
$emparray = array();
while($row =mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
{
$emparray[] = $row;
}

//echo json_encode($emparray); //TESTING.. implement to check response from query.

//Write to json file
    $fp = fopen('name.json', 'w');
    fwrite($fp, json_encode($emparray));
    fclose($fp);

// Close connection.
mysqli_close($conn);
?>
```

Comment: what is the problem here ?

Comment: The problem is, i want to send my label.text value to my server page and assign it to an sql value e.g. $tablename = "label.text"; this code will then be executed and generate that specific tables values. at current i just send a request to table values page of 30 tables receive the data, of which there is 92,000 cells and pick and choose what i want from the data on the app, this is initially very slow and takes up a lot of room.

Comment: so you are not able to send the label text value ?

Comment: Yes, i have no idea how to obtain the value of the label and send it to the server. Thanks for helping by the way.

Comment: just use `NSString *value = myLabel.text` to get it and send it as a param in request

Comment: Sorry didn't copy my whole code as its very large but yeah i already have the value in an NSString I just don't know how to post that value using a nsurlsession...

Comment: add your php script code to the question too please

Comment: I have updated the code so that you can see my .php code

Comment: you arent filtering the data with any var in the script ? it will return all rows in that case

Comment: Sorry i am unsure what you mean by this?

Comment: try joining the [chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26424/iosandroidchaosoverflow)

Comment: Tightened wording.